# Summary of Posts by an User

Tags: posts, users, buddypress

i have a buddypress blog at http://thelazy.info . When I click on a user his buddypress profile opens up. Can there be a summary of his posts in his buddy profile or directly that opening up when user clicks on the person's name besides his post.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is YES. I'm pretty sure it can. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You'd want to put this template in your (child) theme, and edit it:
/members/single/member-header.php

If you don't want it in the header, look in the home.php in that directly and see which template file is included.

You should then be able to use the normal WordPress loop, something like:
$your_loop = get_posts( 'author=' . bp_displayed_user_id() );